# Azure CosmosDB Batch insert ComputeInternalError

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

When executing a TransactionalBatch it returns a forbidden error. 
When I check the Diagnostics in the response, I can see that the `SubStatusCode` is `ComputeInternalError`.

When I search for this type of error I get zero results on Google.
What is this error telling me? How can I fix it?

This is the complete (redacted) Diagnostics from the response:

```
{
    "name": "ExecuteAsync",
    "id": "<redacted>",
    "caller info": {
        "member": "OperationHelperWithRootTraceAsync",
        "file": "ClientContextCore.cs",
        "line": 219
    },
    "start time": "12:47:58:185",
    "duration in milliseconds": 292.1597,
    "data": {
        "Client Configuration": {
            "Client Created Time Utc": "2021-08-30T12:46:26.5148538Z",
            "NumberOfClientsCreated": 1,
            "User Agent": "cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.20.1|3.19.3|1|X64|Microsoft Windows 10.0.19042|.NET 5.0.9|N|",
            "ConnectionConfig": {
                "gw": "(cps:50, urto:10, p:False, httpf: False)",
                "rntbd": "(cto: 5, icto: -1, mrpc: 30, mcpe: 65535, erd: False, pr: ReuseUnicastPort)",
                "other": "(ed:False, be:False)"
            },
            "ConsistencyConfig": "(consistency: NotSet, prgns:[])"
        }
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Execute Next Batch",
            "id": "<redacted>",
            "caller info": {
                "member": "ExecuteAsync",
                "file": "BatchExecutor.cs",
                "line": 44
            },
            "start time": "12:47:58:186",
            "duration in milliseconds": 290.9772,
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Create Batch Request",
                    "id": "<redacted>",
                    "caller info": {
                        "member": "CreateAsync",
                        "file": "SinglePartitionKeyServerBatchRequest.cs",
                        "line": 52
                    },
                    "start time": "12:47:58:188",
                    "duration in milliseconds": 101.1877
                },
                {
                    "name": "Execute Batch Request",
                    "id": "<redacted>",
                    "caller info": {
                        "member": "ExecuteServerRequestAsync",
                        "file": "BatchExecutor.cs",
                        "line": 81
                    },
                    "start time": "12:47:58:290",
                    "duration in milliseconds": 186.8077,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RequestInvokerHandler",
                            "id": "<redacted>",
                            "start time": "12:47:58:290",
                            "duration in milliseconds": 168.1416,
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.DiagnosticsHandler",
                                    "id": "<redacted>",
                                    "start time": "12:47:58:290",
                                    "duration in milliseconds": 168.0172,
                                    "data": {
                                        "CPU Load History": {
                                            "CPU History": "(2021-08-30T12:46:26.9586842Z 25.000), (2021-08-30T12:46:56.9678395Z 33.333), (2021-08-30T12:47:16.9629830Z 0.000), (2021-08-30T12:47:26.9605546Z 9.245), (2021-08-30T12:47:36.9619653Z 0.000), (2021-08-30T12:47:58.1734808Z 9.199)"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RetryHandler",
                                            "id": "<redacted>",
                                            "start time": "12:47:58:290",
                                            "duration in milliseconds": 168.0093,
                                            "children": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RouterHandler",
                                                    "id": "<redacted>",
                                                    "start time": "12:47:58:290",
                                                    "duration in milliseconds": 167.9875,
                                                    "children": [
                                                        {
                                                            "name": "Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.TransportHandler",
                                                            "id": "<redacted>",
                                                            "start time": "12:47:58:290",
                                                            "duration in milliseconds": 167.9816,
                                                            "children": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "name": "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServerStoreModel Transport Request",
                                                                    "id": "<redacted>",
                                                                    "caller info": {
                                                                        "member": "ProcessMessageAsync",
                                                                        "file": "TransportHandler.cs",
                                                                        "line": 109
                                                                    },
                                                                    "start time": "12:47:58:290",
                                                                    "duration in milliseconds": 167.9315,
                                                                    "data": {
                                                                        "Client Side Request Stats": {
                                                                            "Id": "<redacted>",
                                                                            "ContactedReplicas": [
                                                                                {
                                                                                    "Count": 1,
                                                                                    "Uri": "rntbd://<redacted>"
                                                                                },
                                                                                {
                                                                                    "Count": 1,
                                                                                    "Uri": "rntbd://<redacted>"
                                                                                },
                                                                                {
                                                                                    "Count": 1,
                                                                                    "Uri": "rntbd://<redacted>"
                                                                                }
                                                                            ],
                                                                            "RegionsContacted": [
                                                                                "https://<redacted>.documents.azure.com/"
                                                                            ],
                                                                            "FailedReplicas": [],
                                                                            "AddressResolutionStatistics": [],
                                                                            "StoreResponseStatistics": [
                                                                                {
                                                                                    "ResponseTimeUTC": "2021-08-30T12:47:58.4586683Z",
                                                                                    "ResourceType": "Document",
                                                                                    "OperationType": "Batch",
                                                                                    "LocationEndpoint": "https://<redacted>.documents.azure.com/",
                                                                                    "StoreResult": {
                                                                                        "ActivityId": "<redacted>",
                                                                                        "StatusCode": "MultiStatus",
                                                                                        "SubStatusCode": "ComputeInternalError",
                                                                                        "LSN": 308271,
                                                                                        "PartitionKeyRangeId": "0",
                                                                                        "GlobalCommittedLSN": 308271,
                                                                                        "ItemLSN": -1,
                                                                                        "UsingLocalLSN": false,
                                                                                        "QuorumAckedLSN": 308271,
                                                                                        "SessionToken": "-1#308271",
                                                                                        "CurrentWriteQuorum": 3,
                                                                                        "CurrentReplicaSetSize": 4,
                                                                                        "NumberOfReadRegions": 0,
                                                                                        "IsClientCpuOverloaded": false,
                                                                                        "IsValid": true,
                                                                                        "StorePhysicalAddress": "rntbd://<redacted>",
                                                                                        "RequestCharge": 1.67,
                                                                                        "BELatencyInMs": "0.726",
                                                                                        "RntbdRequestStats": [
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                "EventName": "Created",
                                                                                                "StartTime": "2021-08-30T12:47:58.2909371Z",
                                                                                                "DurationInMicroSec": "9"
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                "EventName": "ChannelAcquisitionStarted",
                                                                                                "StartTime": "2021-08-30T12:47:58.2909469Z",
                                                                                                "DurationInMicroSec": "131386"
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                "EventName": "Pipelined",
                                                                                                "StartTime": "2021-08-30T12:47:58.4223335Z",
                                                                                                "DurationInMicroSec": "1098"
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                "EventName": "Transit Time",
                                                                                                "StartTime": "2021-08-30T12:47:58.4234318Z",
                                                                                                "DurationInMicroSec": "34423"
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                "EventName": "Received",
                                                                                                "StartTime": "2021-08-30T12:47:58.4578548Z",
                                                                                                "DurationInMicroSec": "778"
                                                                                            },
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                "EventName": "Completed",
                                                                                                "StartTime": "2021-08-30T12:47:58.4586336Z",
                                                                                                "DurationInMicroSec": "0"
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        ],
                                                                                        "TransportException": null
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            ]
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Create Trace",
                            "id": "<redacted>",
                            "caller info": {
                                "member": "FromResponseMessageAsync",
                                "file": "TransactionalBatchResponse.cs",
                                "line": 214
                            },
                            "start time": "12:47:58:461",
                            "duration in milliseconds": 15.8089
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allright, found the problem. I am using a Serverless container, which has a max capacity of 50 GB. The database was at 49.56 GB.
After deleting the test data it works again.